# Jquery not running during call to another page via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have Index page, from index page I called Jquery and PHP page (combined in one.php file), if I run one.php file alone everything running fine, But if I call same page via Ajax then it's not running.

**Sample Code:**

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>mouseover demo</title>
        <script src="script/javaScript.js"></script>
    </head>        
    <body>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="addpage()">click</a>
        <div id="view"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "div[class^=star]" ).mouseover(function() {
        $( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse Over" );  
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse Out" );   
    }); 
});

function addpage(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{ // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){          
            document.getElementById("view").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","one.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**one.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>mouseover demo</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
        <script src="script/javaScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="staroverout">
                        <span>move cursor to change text</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="staroverout">
                        <span>move cursor to change text</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="nstaroverout">
                        <span>move cursor to change text</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you make things easier on yourself and use [jQuery AJAX methods?](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: And where do you use the `one.php`?  I see `change-text-mouseover.php`

Comment: there is 2 things which needs to be corrected here. 1.why dont u use the jquery `$.ajax()` which is much simple and easy to use than raw Javascript code for ajax call. 2.your php page doesnt contain any php code at all, so as far as i know unless and until u dont `echo` the data from php page nothing would be returned to calling page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using jQuery, but you forgot to include it (in your `index.php`):

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script/javaScript.js"></script>
   ```
2. When you fetch data with Ajax, you should use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for attaching events to elements:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('body').on('mouseover', "div[class^=star]", function() {
           $( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse Over" );  
       }).on('mouseout', "div[class^=star]", function() {
           $( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse Out" );   
       });
   });
   ```
3. Remove the extra elements (`html`, `head`, `script`) from your `one.php` file:

   ```
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <div class="staroverout">
                   <span>move cursor to change text</span>
               </div>
               <br>
               <div class="staroverout">
                   <span>move cursor to change text</span>
               </div>
               <br>
               <div class="nstaroverout">
                   <span>move cursor to change text</span>
               </div>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```
4. If you are using jQuery, as you do, sent Ajax requests with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

Answer (score 0):

How about if you try removing those jquery.js in one.php.

because the jquery is already included in the page once when you again include it in the page "one.php", I gets included again which causes `JQuery Conflict`